# redirect desktop users to another page and mobile user to the main page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, redirect

I have a problem with this code.I want to redirect my desktop users to block.php page and dont let them in.

i tested a lot of code and non of them work for me.

at the moment,i found this code.its works perfectly...but there is e tiny problem.

when i check my site with mobile ( ios device )..it keeps *reloading*

this is the code :

```js
<script>

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) { 
    window.location.assign("http://example.com"); 
} else { 
    window.location.assign("http://example.com/block.php"); 
} 

</script>
```

what is the problem?

Comment: you have try .htaccess?

Comment: @keronconk no..i wanna use JS...but how is it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this script is running on http://example.com, calling window.location.assign inside of the if block would reload the page. It seems to me like you want to call window.location.assign('http://example.com/block.php') only if the user is NOT on a mobile device.

You could try something like this:

```js
function checkIsMobile () {
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)){
    return true;
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)){
      return true;
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }

if (!checkIsMobile()) { 
    window.location.assign("http://example.com/block.php"); 
}
```

Comment: thank you...it works now...but it can be tricked with User Agent Switcher extention in firefox or chrome..is there any solution for that?

Comment: Most people recommend using feature detection instead of UA sniffing since it is easy, as you note, to spoof that info. Even using feature detection, there will be no 100% accuracy with this type of task since the device ecosystem is so broad. Check out this article on feature detection here for more info: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/detection/

Comment: Hmm...works for me, here it is again: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/detection/ if it doesn't work, just throw https:// in front of the path and paste into browser